# Stata and global variables

Tags: global, stata

I am working with Stata.
I have a variable called `graduate_secondary`.
I generate a global variable called `outcome`, because eventually I will use another outcome.
Now I want to replace  the variable graduate if a condition relative to global is met, but I get an error:

My code is:

```
global outcome "graduate_secondary"

gen graduate=.

replace graduate=1 if graduate_primary==1 & `outcome'==1
```

But i receive the symbol `==1` invalid name.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Although global macros can be used like variables in other software, in Stata they are customarily called that, not global variables. https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-08/msg01258.html said more.

Comment: I recommend not using Stata, try learning other languages like Pyhton or R which are open source and substantially more popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along those lines might work (using a reproducible example):

```
sysuse auto, clear        
global outcome "rep78"

gen graduate=.

replace graduate=1 if mpg==22 & $outcome==3
(2 real changes made)
```

In your example, just use

```
replace graduate=1 if graduate_primary==1 & $outcome==1
```

would work.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to replace `global outcome "graduate_secondary"` with `local outcome "graduate_secondary"`.

Stata has two types of macros: global, which are accessed with a `$`, and local, which are accessed with single quotes `' around the name -- as you did in your original code.

You get an error message because a local by the name of *outcome* has no value assigned to it in your workspace. By design, this will not itself produce an error but instead will the reference to the macro will evaluate as a blank value. You can see the result of evaluating macro references when you type them by using `display` as follows. You can also see all of the macros in your workspace with `macro dir` (the locals start with an underscore):

```
display `outcome'
display $outcome
```

[Here](https://blog.stata.com/2015/11/03/programming-an-estimation-command-in-stata-global-macros-versus-local-macros/) is a blog post about using macros in Stata. In general, I only use global macros when I have to pass something between multiple routines, but this seems like a good use case for locals.

Comment: (+1) Nice explanation. https://www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf is indispensable reading for Stata programmers. The manuals are also bundled with your Stata installation on your machine as pdf documentation.